# Not logging out after Cookie expiration

Tags: php, session-cookies, setcookie

I have setcookie set to +60 for 60 seconds while testing. It is not logging me out after the cookie expiration in the browser. The cookie in the browser expires and disapears from settings in Chrome, but I am still logged in. Hope this makes sense.

It's for a project I am working on. I am trying to set the cookie to expire and logout after a period of time for security reasons.

```
       /****************User login functions ********************/


function login_user($email, $password, $remember) {


    $sql = "SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = '".escape($email)."' AND active = 1";

    $result = query($sql);

    if(row_count($result) == 1) {

        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_password = $row['password'];


        if(md5($password) === $db_password) {

            if($remember == "on") {

            setcookie('email', $email, time()+60, '/');

            }


            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;



            return true;

        } else {


            return false;
        }
    }



} // end of function



    /****************logged in function ********************/



    function logged_in(){


if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email'])){


    return true;

} else {


    return false;
}




    }   // functions
```

My logout is:

```
       session_destroy();


if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {

    unset($_COOKIE['email']);

    setcookie('email', '', time()-60);


}

    redirect("../login.php");
```

Not getting any errors. It's just not doing what it is meant to do.

Answer (score -1):

your logout codes needs to check of cookie is not set, that means cookie already expired. what you are doing is checking if cookie is set, when  cookie has already expired that if statement won't work. try the following code.

put the following code in logout function.

```
session_destroy();
setcookie('email', '', time()-60, '/');
redirect("../login.php");
```

Put this code in the header

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {
     //logout(); call the logout function here.
}
```

Comment: @user3719039 i edited my answer and explained a little more, hope it works now, please try it.

Comment: i forgot to add the path in the setcookie above, please try now, it should work, and it will only logout when user refreshes the page.

Comment: you need to set redirects correctly, if logout successful then redirect to landing page or if login successful redirect to home page or dashboard where ever you want to take the user,

Comment: don't set authentication priority on cookies as it's very insecure way to implement authentication, user can turn off cookies in the browser and your authentication might fail. I'll suggest using server sessions.

Comment: post the code where you check if user is logged in or not ?

Comment: `// Check if Logged in
  if(logged_in()) {

    echo 'Logged In!';

  }else{
    redirect('./login.php');
  }`

Comment: `function logged_in(){


 if(isset($_SESSION['email']) || isset($_COOKIE['email'])){


  return true;

 } else {


  return false;
 }




} // functions`